# React redirects to home page on page refresh need to stay on same

Tags: reactjs

When a user refreshes the current page, react redirects it to home page.

How do I prevent this? On force refresh page url should not change. I have tried HashRouter also, but no luck.

can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong ?

I'm using:

```
"react": "^16.11.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

My index.js file:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); 

eactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); 
App.js

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import BaseRouter from './routes';
import CustomLayout from './containers/Layout';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
            <CustomLayout {...this.props}>
              <BaseRouter />
            </CustomLayout>
          </Router>

        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The relevant part of routes.js file:

```
        <React.Fragment>
            {!token ? <Redirect to='/login/' /> :
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
                    <Route exact path='/customers/' component={Customers} />
                    <Route exact path='/some-route/' component={someRoute} />
                    <Route component={Page404} />`enter code here`
                </Switch>
            }
        </React.Fragment>`enter code here`
```

Comment: where did the `token` come from ??

Comment: you don't need a slash at the end.

Comment: @Anamika are you sure your token isn't undefined or null?

Comment: @vahid yes token isn't having undefined and null otherwise it will logout from page

Comment: @Deda  you don't need a slash at the end - i have removed slash from the end

Comment: @Anamika why don't you keep loggedin condition in componentDidMount() of root component.

Comment: @Anamika can you share your code in sandbox to check?

Answer (score -1):

This is the syntax by official docs.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/'>
        <HomePage />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path='/customers'>
        <Customers />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path='/some-route'>
        <SomeRoute />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```